# Redis cache setup in magento 1.11.2.0

Tags: magento-enterprise, redis, cm-redissession

I have setup Cm_RedisSession module on magento version 1.11.2.0. I added this section of code in app/etc/local.xml

```
<session_save>db</session_save>
    <redis_session>                       <!-- All options seen here are the defaults -->
        <host>127.0.0.1</host>            <!-- Specify an absolute path if using a unix socket -->
        <port>6379</port>
        <password></password>             <!-- Specify if your Redis server requires authentication -->
        <timeout>2.5</timeout>            <!-- This is the Redis connection timeout, not the locking timeout -->
        <persistent></persistent>         <!-- Specify unique string to enable persistent connections. E.g.: sess-db0; bugs with phpredis and php-fpm are known: https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis/issues/70 -->
        <db>0</db>                        <!-- Redis database number; protection from accidental loss is improved by using a unique DB number for sessions -->
        <compression_threshold>2048</compression_threshold>  <!-- Set to 0 to disable compression (recommended when suhosin.session.encrypt=on); known bug with strings over 64k: https://github.com/colinmollenhour/Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis/issues/18 -->
        <compression_lib>gzip</compression_lib>              <!-- gzip, lzf or snappy -->
        <log_level>1</log_level>               <!-- 0 (emergency: system is unusable), 4 (warning; additional information, recommended), 5 (notice: normal but significant condition), 6 (info: informational messages), 7 (debug: the most information for development/testing) -->
        <max_concurrency>6</max_concurrency>                 <!-- maximum number of processes that can wait for a lock on one session; for large production clusters, set this to at least 10% of the number of PHP processes -->
        <break_after_frontend>5</break_after_frontend>       <!-- seconds to wait for a session lock in the frontend; not as critical as admin -->
        <break_after_adminhtml>30</break_after_adminhtml>
        <bot_lifetime>7200</bot_lifetime>                    <!-- Bots get shorter session lifetimes. 0 to disable -->
    </redis_session>
```

I am unable to check that my redis cache is setup properly or not.I read in some site that redis cache stored in server so I tried this commands in 'terminal' to check.

```
redis-cli monitor
```

After hitting this command ,it only show 'ok'. I also tried

```
redis-cli info
```

But it didn't the cache information.
How do I check that my module and server configuration setup properly or not.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

If everything is working fine, then there are no session storage either in magento filesystem (var/session) or in database. Now the sessions are stored in the redis database that you define in the tag . 
As you have defined database 0, then you can see the session files in this database from [redis admin](https://github.com/ErikDubbelboer/phpRedisAdmin/).

Comment: $ redis-cli INFO | grep ^db

Comment: but first redis session extension is disabled by default, so you have to set it to `true`

Answer (score 0):

**Verifying Redis server**

To test Redis server, we simply ping it using:

```
redis-cli ping
```

If you have received your `PONG`, means it is Redis server is loaded.

**Verifying PhpRedis extension**

To see if Redis extension is being loaded by PHP we can grep the output of php -m shell command:

```
php -m | grep redis
```

We expect string `redis` as a result.

[More reading](http://inchoo.net/magento/using-redis-cache-backend-and-session-storage-in-magento/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7669508/how-can-i-test-if-my-redis-cache-is-working)

Comment: Thanks. I have used the above command. I have got the expected result after hitting the commands as 'PONG' and 'redis'. But How do I check that redis is configured well with magento or not ? Where do I check stored cache ?

Comment: If everything is working then your /var/cache folder should remain empty.

Comment: This doesn't actually verify that Magento is using redis though, only that the connection works

Comment: lol if folder is empty the sessions stored in redis... nice debug approach...